# Ubuntu Bash cron heredoc doesn't work

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I login to my remote machine as the user `root`, then running the following script that needs to add some scheduled tasks to Unix cron:

```
#!/bin/bash

su USERNAME

crontab -l 2>/dev/null

cat <<- 'EOF'

       * * * * * cron-task1...
       * * * * * cron-task1...

       * * * * * cron-task2...
       * * * * * cron-task2...

       * * * * * cron-task3...
       * * * * * cron-task3...

EOF

exit
```

For some reason this code doesn't work, i.e, after execution, **the cron  tasks won't be printed to the cron from the heredoc**, yet the task codes are fine as if I copy them manually like in `crontab -e`, they work just fine.

What might be wrong with the above code? Thank you,

---

### Update for Chev_603:

If I execute:

```
su USERNAME

sudo cat <<- 'EOF' > cron.jobs
* * * * * CRON TASKS...
EOF
```

I get:

> bash: cron.jobs: Permission denied

If I would use a file I would just change ownership, group and permissions as in `sudo chmod +x /home/user/Location/Of/Script` but given it's a heredoc, I guess it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite this being marked as a duplicate, I answered it because the issue was that both the syntax of `cat` and `crontab` were off.

There is no existing crontab, and your syntax is off. For example, if I do this with no cron configured, this happens:

```
$ crontab -l
no crontab for anon
```

And than you're simply sending the contents of the here doc to stdout.

So first create a crontab file like this:

```
cat <<- 'EOF' > cron.jobs

   * * * * * cron-task1...
   * * * * * cron-task2...
   * * * * * cron-task3...

EOF

crontab cron.jobs
```

Than confirm it worked:

```
crontab -l
 * * * * * cron-task1...
 * * * * * cron-task2...
 * * * * * cron-task3...
```

The reason why it wasn't working is because `crontab -l` simply displays the contents of the users cron file to stdout:

From `man crontab`:

```
   The -l option causes the current crontab to be displayed on standard output. See the note under DEBIAN SPECIFIC below.
```

Also, instead of using `su` , you can use

```
cat cron.jobs |crontab -u user -
```

Putting it all together, add this to a script, say `cron.sh` and try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="$@"
cat <<- 'EOF' > cron.jobs

   * * * * * cron-task1...
   * * * * * cron-task2...
   * * * * * cron-task3...

EOF


cat cron.jobs|crontab -u $user -
```

And then:

`bash cron.sh username`

But I think what you were going for was more like:

```
cat <<< '
* * * * *  cron-task1... ' |crontab -
```

Comment: I would very much like to do it only with su USERNAME but I get permission denied when doing this with su USERNAME... i.e when I do sudo cat <<- 'EOF' > cron.jobs, I get permission denied.

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: Chev_603, can you please give me your opinion on the permissions issue?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, if I remove cat, the command doesn't work for me...

Comment: Which instance of `cat` did you remove and what exactly did you substitute? I was thinking of: `crontab -u user cron.jobs` and `crontab - <<< '* * * * * command'`. You can even skip the intermediate file for the heredoc.

Comment: Just removed cat, no substitute. I am very new to this. Just wanted to note that.

Comment: @Benia - I *think* that is because your current shell process forks when you call sudo. It than tries to open cron.jobs  for writing, and the file descriptor becomes standard output, causing only sudo to execute... but don't quote me on that..  If you really want to it that way, try this: `sudo bash -c  "cat <<- 'EOF' > cron.jobs EOF`" . That works. Any posix wizards around that can better explain this?

Comment: To better explain my theory... If I add `sudo cat <<< EOF > somefile` to a script and run it with `bash test.sh` and strace it, I see a `bad file descriptor` error. However, running it with `sudo bash test.sh` works fine: http://sprunge.us/VLfC